# The relationship between smooth non-vanishing $(0,s)$ tensor fields on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

Is it the case that for any two smooth non-vanishing $(0,s)$ tensor fields $\alpha_{b_1...b_s}$ and $\beta_{b_1...b_s}$ on an $n$-dimensional manifold (and where $2 \leq s \leq n$), there exists a smooth non-vanishing scalar field $f$ such that $\beta_{b_1...b_s} = f\alpha_{b_1...b_s}$?

In my textbook (Malament 2012, p. 112), this is said to hold for $n$-forms, but the reasoning seems to apply more generally. I'd like to ask if there are some mistakes in the following:

Suppose $\{\stackrel{1}{\xi^b}, ..., \stackrel{n}{\xi^b}\}$ is a basis for tangent space at a given point in $M$, and $\{\stackrel{1}{\eta^b}, ..., \stackrel{n}{\eta^b}\}$ is a dual basis. Then, for any $1 \leq i_1 \leq ... \leq i_s \leq n$, one can express $\alpha_{b_1...b_s}$ as $(*)$:

$$\alpha_{b_1...b_s} = k_\alpha \ s!\ \stackrel{i_1}{\eta}_{[b_1}...\stackrel{i_s}{\eta}_{b_s]}$$

where

$$k_\alpha = \alpha_{b_1...b_s}\stackrel{i_1}{\xi^{b_1}}...\stackrel{i_s}{\xi^{b_s}}$$

This hold because both sides of $(*)$ have the same action on any combination of $n$ vectors from $\{\stackrel{1}{\xi^b}, ..., \stackrel{n}{\xi^b}\}$ - to see this note that after expanding the anti-symmetrization from the right-hand side $s!\times(1/s!)=1$, the first term yields gives $\alpha_{b_1...b_s}\stackrel{i_1}{\xi^b}...\stackrel{i_n}{\xi^b}$, and the other terms are vanishing as they have $\stackrel{i}{\xi^{b_k}}\stackrel{j}{\eta}_{b_k} = 0$ for some $i\neq j$. But then it seems that for any $\alpha_{b_1...b_s}$ and $\beta_{b_1...b_s}$, we have:

$$\beta_{b_1...b_s} = \frac{k_\beta}{k_\alpha}\alpha_{b_1...b_s}$$.

Comment: i might be missing something, but i don't think thats true considering $dx\wedge dy$ and $dy\wedge dz$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: I may have some difficulties following the notation, but your $k_\alpha$ must imply a sum convention for $s\neq n$? So it's not just simply a scalar function as for the case $n =s$. In that sense the last line doesn't really work in general.

Comment: @P-A I’m using abstract index notation. $k_\alpha$ is a scalar field: $i_1,…, i_s$ are fixed from the beginning.

Comment: @RollenS.D'Souza Sorry, I’m not sure I get what you mean.

Comment: But you cannot just fix the $i_j$, since an arbitrary tensor will be a linear combination of your basis vectors. Hence you'll end up with a sum of different coefficients $k_\alpha$ and the argument doesn't work. It works for $s=n$ however, since any tensor there is spanned by one element only due to the antisymmetry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, for the simple fact that you’re no longer dealing (pointwise) with a $1$-dimensional vector space.

As a very concrete example, consider on $\Bbb{R}^n$ ($n\geq 2$), $\alpha=dx\otimes dx$ and $\beta=dy\otimes dy$. These are nowhere vanishing $(0,2)$ tensor fields on $\Bbb{R}^n$, but they’re not multiples of each other.

I’m not sure why you’re talking about (anti-)symmetrization because you made no such assumptions on $\alpha,\beta$.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. I meant expanding the antisymmetrisation of the $\eta$s from RHS of (*)

Comment: @fr_ yea still, why did you do that? You didn’t assume $\alpha$ is alternating, so how can that equality be true?

Comment: No I didn’t assume $\alpha$ is alternating. But does it matter? If I expand the antisymmetrized $\eta$s, the first term will give 1 when acted on by the $\xi^s$, but all the other terms should vanish, so the equality should hold.